# Coded UI browserWindow.Launch() invoke issue, after latest chrome update

Tags: coded-ui-tests

After the latest Chrome browser update (54.0), I am unable to invoke BrowserWindow.Launch() properly through ChromeDriver.

**Issue being experienced:**

- Multiple window is are being opened, but there is no control on new window created.
- A null pointer exception is throwing on windowHandle.

**Resolution tried:**

1. New ChromeDriver 2.25 updated
2. Latest CodeUITestCrossbrowsersetup installed

Please suggest if any more update need to be done or alternative ways to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the existing [bugs for ChromeDriver](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/list) for your issue? Have you tried rolling back to previous versions?

Comment: For previous version its working fine .. Chrome 53.0 and chromedriver older than 2.24.

Comment: I think the same issue is being discussed in https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d/view/Discussions